# Preserve sizes range when adding multiple seaborn scatterplots to the same axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm adding multiple `seaborn` `scatterplot`s to the same axis, and want to ensure the dot size corresponds to the same size value in each.

For example, suppose I want to plot smokers separately from non-smokers in the `tips` dataset, e.g. to assign different `alpha` values, and that I want to size by `size`. The maximum `size` value differs between smokers and non-smokers, so the sizes will have different meanings:

```
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

ax = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", size="size", sizes=(10, 100),
                     data=tips[tips.smoker == "Yes"], alpha=0.8)
sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", size="size", sizes=(10, 100),
                data=tips[tips.smoker == "No"], alpha=1.0, ax=ax)
```

[image: scatterplot]

```
tips.groupby('smoker')['size'].max()
# smoker
# Yes    5
# No     6
```

Passing a dictionary like `sizes={1:10, 6:100}` doesn't work, as the dictionary requires all the levels to be specified:

> ValueError: Missing sizes for the following levels: {2, 3, 4, 5}

Is there a way to specify a consistent scale?